# Github public key doesn't work returning permission denied

Tags: github, ssh

I used github and today I can't push commits and clone repos.
I'm getting error `git@github.com Permission denied (publickey)`
I generated public key and I used it and it worked. I also see my public key in my github account.

The public key which I genereated is ssh-ed25519

Maybe i should add this key once again to my local git account? But i don't know how

Do you know whats happed that the public key doens't work?

Comment: To test your public key with GitHub, run `ssh -Tv git@github.com`. See the [GitHub help pages](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection), and in particular [the one on what to do if you're getting the exact error that you are getting](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey).

Answer (score 0):

You can look at .git/config, under [remote "origin"] there was, before commits and clone:

```
url = http://github.com/path/to/repository
```

or

```
url = https://github.com/path/to/repository
```

you can change the link with ssh:

```
url = ssh://git@github.com/path/to/repository
```

Good Luck

Comment: If the OP is getting a complaint about `publickey`, they're already using ssh. Diagnosing the problem involves working with ssh, not with Git.